# freeradius unlang disable escaping

Tags: ldap-query, freeradius

I have the following list of VLAN's I want to check against ldap.

```
Tmp-String-0 = "CN=vlan10,CN=Users,DC=aaa,DC=local;CN=vlan20,CN=Users,DC=aaa,DC=local"
```

With ulang I explode them and loop through them

```
 if ("%{explode:&control:Tmp-String-0 ;}" > 0) {
           foreach &control:Tmp-String-0 {
```

Then I try to do checking with

```
Tmp-String-1 := "%{ldap_aaa.local:ldapi://192.168.0.199:389/cn=Users,dc=aaa,dc=local?memberof?sub?(&(objectCategory=User)(sAMAccountName=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})(memberOf=%{Foreach-Variable-0}))}"
```

However `%{Foreach-Variable-0}` gets the escaped version of the string:

`CN3dvlan202cCN3dUsers2cDC3daaa2cDC3dlocal`

The escaped version is not working, if I replace it with hardcoded unescaped version the it works.

`CN=vlan20,CN=Users,DC=aaa,DC=local`

How to prevent unlang for escaping the variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent unescaping in v3.  In version 4 there's the concept of "tainted" and "untainted" values, with tainted values being escaped, and "untainted" values being inserted verbatim, but I'm not sure that's implemented yet in the LDAP module expansions.

You could use the group membership checks in the LDAP module to do what you're trying to implement with the xlat expansion?

e.g.

```
 if ("%{explode:&control:Tmp-String-0 ;}" > 0) {
           foreach &control:Tmp-String-0 {
                      if (LDAP-Group == "%{control:Tmp-String-0}") {
                                 update reply {
                                            # VLAN-Attrs
                                 }
                      }
           }
}
```